# In Python, can I prevent a function from catching KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit?

Tags: python, exception

I am writing some code in Python something like this:

```
import sys
try:
    for x in large_list:
        function_that_catches_KeyboardInterrupt(x)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Canceled!"
    sys.exit(1)
```

When I try to interrupt the loop, I basically need to hold down <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  long enough to cancel every invocation of the function for all the elements of `large-list`, and only then does my program exit.

Is there any way I can prevent the function from catching KeyboardInterrupt so that I can catch it myself? The only way I can think of would be to abuse threading by creating a separate thread just for calling the function, but that seems excessive.

Edit: I checked the offending code (which I can't easily change), and it actually uses a bare `except:`, so even `sys.exit(1)` is caught as a `SystemExit` exception. How can I escape from the bare `except:` block and quit my program?

Comment: Doesn't seem that excessive to me... also because every other solution I can come up with would involve some kind of black magic...

Comment: Note that you don't need to use a thread for each invocation, only one is enough. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rebind the SIGINT handler using the [signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) library.

```
import signal, sys
def handler(signal, frame):
    print "Canceled!"
    sys.exit(1)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
for x in large_list:
    function_that_catches_KeyboardInterrupt(x)
```

There are a few ways that one can exit when `SystemExit` is being caught. `os._exit(1)` will do a c-style exit with no cleanup. `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)` will allow the interpreter some level of cleanup, I believe flushing/closing file handles, etc.

Comment: I think he wants the signal to be caught by the outer exception handler, though -- just not by the code inside the function. This would suppress it entirely

Comment: Then he can replace the sys.exit call with something that hands control back to his program. You're already dealing with flow control hijacking, I don't think you're going to find a more elegant solution ;)

Comment: Could I just replace `sys.exit` with `raise KeyboardInterrupt()`? Or would I need to use a different exception?

Comment: That is exactly what the default handler does. The signal handler is a callback that is called internally by the interpreter. You could technically raise a different exception, but I suspect this would be unhelpful. Most functions will not explicitly catch KeyboardInterrupt, but instead catch it accidentally by using a blanket `except:` block rather than the idiomatic `except Exception:` block, and will therefore also quash any custom exceptions you try to throw.

Comment: Also, pretty much all I want to do when the KeyboardInterrupt happens is `sys.exit(1)`, so I don't care how it gets caught, I just want to catch it. But is there any way to undo this after the loop is finished?

Comment: Yes. `signal.signal` returns the old handler, so you can do `default_sigint_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler) ; SOME MISBEHAVING CODE ; signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, default_sigint_handler)`

Comment: Ok, cool. The other problem is that the misbehaving code also catches SystemExit. How do I bypass that?

Comment: That one's a bit tougher, since SystemExit is baked pretty deep into the interpreter. As a general rule I don't know of a good way to do it. In this case, where you just want to really exit despite misbehaving code, you can call `os._exit(1)` for a really dirty exit, or `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)` for an only slightly less dirty exit (I believe this will flush file handles, etc).

Comment: Yay, `os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)` worked! Do you want to add it to your answer for posterity?